# Sorting an Array of Strings in C using functions

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void bubble_sort_grades(char [], int); 
int main(void)
{
    int menuswitch=1;
    int amountofstudents;
    int i;
    int z;
    char studentinfo[100];
    char fname[50][100];
    char lname[50][100];
    char grade[50][100];
    printf("Enter Amount of Students: ");
    scanf("%d ", &amountofstudents);
    for (i=0;i<amountofstudents;i++)
    {
        fgets(studentinfo, sizeof(studentinfo), stdin);
        strcpy(fname[i], strtok(studentinfo, " "));
        strcpy(lname[i], strtok(NULL, " "));
        strcpy(grade[i], strtok(NULL, " "));
    }
        while (menuswitch==1)
        {
            int answer;
            printf("Enter 1 for Alphabetical Sort (First Name) \n");
            printf("Enter 2 for Alphabetical Sort (Last Name) \n");
            printf("Enter 3 for Score Sort \n");
            printf("Enter 0 to exit \n");
            printf("Enter choice now: ");
            scanf("%d", &answer);
            if (answer==1)
            {
                bubble_sort_grades(grade,amountofstudents);
                printf("%s\n", grade[0]);
                printf("%s\n", grade[1]);
            }
            if (answer==2)
            {
                printf("In 2 \n");
            }
            if (answer==3)
            {
                printf("In 3 \n");
            }
            if (answer==0)
            {
                printf("Ending Program \n");
                menuswitch=0;
            }
        }
}
void bubble_sort_grades(char grades2[], int amount)
{
    int c, d , t;
    for (c=0; c<(amount); c++)
    {
        for (d=0; d<amount-1; d++)
        {
            if (grades2[c]>grades2[d+1])
            {
                t=grades2[d+1];
                grades2[d+1]=grades2[d];
                grades2[d]=t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for asking another questions but I need help on bubble sorting. I created a function to bubble sort the grades of students from the input. Yet, when I do this I get only the first grade sorted instead of the array.

```
   Input:
    John Smith 86
    Victor Jones 76
```

Output:
68
76

Comment: And what where you expecting as output?

Comment: The Wikipedia article has a good explanation of bubble sort. You should be able to implement yours using the examples there. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: i want it to be in increasing order 76 then 86 instead its just sorting the first string in the array (86)

Comment: Just to get this to build, I had to change some of your prototypes to `char grade[50][100];`.  Did it build this way for you?  I think the code you have here does not match what you are actually using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two main problems here.

**Problem 1: Incorrect array indexing**

As @TWhite already pointed out, the parameter for your bubble-sort function has the wrong type. You've declared your arrays to be of type `char[50][100]`, which means it allocates 50*100 characters as a single large block in memory. If your memory for `grade` is allocated at `baseAddr`, then `grade[0]` is at `baseAddr+0`, `grade[1]` is at `baseAddr+100`, `grade[2]` is at `baseAddr+200`, etc. If you don't tell `bubble_sort_grades` the last dimension of your 2D-array, then it has no way calculate these indices. Changing the signature of `bubble_sort_grades` to `void bubble_sort_grades(char[][100], int)` would fix that problem.

**Problem 2: You're storing c-strings but treating them like ints**

The `grade` array is an array of c-strings (`char*`). It stores characters, not ints. That means that this line is totally wrong: `if (grades2[c]>grades2[d+1])` (***Side note:** Notice that you're using `c` instead of `d` as the first index, which is also an error*). If you want to compare strings, you should instead use `strcmp`, since comparing two `char*` values will with the `>` operator just do a pointer comparison. However, using `strcmp` requires that all the grades be 2 digits (e.g. `05` instead of `5`), otherwise the string `"9"` will be greater than `"80"`. Since the grades are c-strings, that also means `t=grades2[d+1]` is totally incorrect since you're storing a `char*` into an `int`. You'd need to create a temporary buffer `char t[100]`, then use `strcpy` instead of copying things around by assignment.

---

I like @chux's suggestion of using a `struct`. Using structs has the added benefit of automatically (correctly) handling copying the whole struct when you use the `=` operator. I was going to suggest something similar, and actually suggest using the built-in `qsort` routine, but I realize this is probably homework and you may not have covered structs yet. In that case, it's probably easier to just change your `grade` array to store ints instead of c-strings.

Answer (score 2):

A number of issues

Instead of

```
char fname[50][100];
char lname[50][100];
char grade[50][100];
```

Use structure

```
typedef struct {
  char fname[100];
  char lname[100];
  char grade[100];
} Student_t;
Student_t Student[50];
```

Inside `bubble_sort_grades()`, use`strcmp()` to compare names.

```
void bubble_sort_grades(Student_t Student[], int amount) {
  int c, d;
  for (c = 0; c < (amount); c++) {
    for (d = 0; d < amount - 1; d++) {
      if (strcmp(Student[d].grade, Student[d+1].grade) > 0) {
        Student_t t;
        t = Student[d];
        Student[d + 1] = Student[d];
        Student[d] = t;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There area other significant issues, but this should get the OP going.

Comment: Just nitpicking here, but it's a good idea to keep in mind that the `_t` suffix for types is reserved by POSIX. It's hardly going to matter in this particular case, but liberal use of `_t` may lead to problems later.

Comment: @dreamlax Look like I should check into that.  Any reference suggestions?

Comment: See section 2.2.2 [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html). EDIT, updated version [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) (same restriction applies).

Answer (score 1):

One issue is your :

```
void bubble_sort_grades(char [], int);
```

Should be changed to :

```
void bubble_sort_grades(char *[], int);
```

Consider using `char *[]` for all your arrays.

Comment: Maybe you meant `char (*)[100]`?

Comment: TWhite: I like your ninja cow icon— or should I say _ninnyuu_!